# How to use `%` in a batch file

Tags: windows, batch

I want to associate a extension to a program by a batch file.

This command works fine when I write it interactively.

```
ftype wavfile="%ProgramFiles(x86)%\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe" "%1"
```

But when I write it in a batch file and run, then `%1` are recognized as a variable, so it ends up with:

```
ftype wavfile="%ProgramFiles(x86)%\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe" ""
```

I think someone already ask a same question, but I couldn't find it.
How can I use `%1` or some other argument variables in a batch file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use two percentage symbols like this: `%%1`, which will work for a batch file.

It will [escape](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/escapechars.php) the `%%` into a percent sign.