# How to receive a parameter in a batch file

Tags: windows, batch, windows-registry, parameters, arguments

I have asked a question, [Use an environment variable to point to an "Open With" program](https://superuser.com/q/932317/245595), which received [a fantastic answer](https://superuser.com/a/932377/245595).
To add `myapp.exe`, residing in `%MYAPPSDIR%`, to the *Open With* context menu, I should write in the CLI

```
reg add "HKCR\Applications\myapp.exe\shell\open\command" /ve /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /d "\"^%MYAPPSDIR^%\myapp\myapp.exe\" \"^%1\"" /f
```

Now I want to have a `.bat` file, receiving a parameter, which executes that sentence. E.g., executing `regadd.bat myapp.exe` would do it. What should the line in the `.bat` file be?

The points are:

1. How to include the parameter,
2. How to include the parameter with `.exe` removed (for the directory part),
3. How to avoid expanding `%1` that goes into the registry (I do not know how to escape it appropriately).

I found many resources (e.g., [How to use `%` in a batch file](https://superuser.com/q/823716/245595)), but I wouldn't like to tinker with the registry.
My bet for 1 and 3 is (still have to work out 2):

```
reg add "HKCR\Applications\%1\shell\open\command" /ve /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /d "\"^%MYAPPSDIR^%\(%1 with .exe removed)\%1\" \"^%1\"" /f
```

I could also set the `.bat` to be run as `regadd.bat myapp`. In that case, the line would be

```
reg add "HKCR\Applications\%1.exe\shell\open\command" /ve /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /d "\"^%MYAPPSDIR^%\%1\%1.exe\" \"^%1\"" /f
```

I am interested in both options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Batch interpreter parses command line in slightly different manner than pure command line parser (read [answers to another question at StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4094699/3439404)):

- **command line**: to avoid expanding `%MYAPPSDIR%` by command line interpreter, the `%` percent character should be escaped by the standard CLI escape character (`^` caret): `^%MYAPPSDIR^%` or `^%1`;
- **`.bat` script**: to avoid expanding `%MYAPPSDIR%` or `%1` by batch interpreter, the `%` percent character should be **doubled** as follows: `%%MYAPPSDIR%%` and `%%1`, respectively.

To distinguish parameters supplied to your batch script:

```
set "par1=%~1"
if "%par1%"=="" (
  echo no parameter supplied
  goto :eof
) else (
  set "par=%par1:.exe=%"
)
if "%par%"=="%par1%" (
  echo .exe not present
) else (
  echo .exe present
)
```

or (maybe better)

```
set "par1=%~1"
if "%par1%"=="" (
  echo no parameter supplied
  goto :eof
) else (
  set "par=%par1:~-4%"
)
if /I "%par%"==".exe" (
  echo .exe present
) else (
  echo .exe not present
)
```

or (maybe the best)

```
set "par1=%~1"
if "%par1%"=="" (
  echo no parameter supplied
  goto :eof
) else (
  set "par=%~x1"
)
if /I "%par%"==".exe" (
  echo .exe present
) else (
  echo .exe not present
)
```

**Resources** (required reading):

- (command reference) [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/)
- (additional particularities) [Windows CMD Shell Command Line Syntax](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax.html)
- (`%~1` etc. special page) [Command Line arguments (Parameters)](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html)
- (`%par1:~-4%` substring) [Variables: extract part of a variable](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-substring.html)
- (`%par1:.exe=%`) [Variable Edit/Replace](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-replace.html)

Comment: @sancho.s Use `%~n1` - expands `%1` to a file name without file extension. See [Command Line arguments (Parameters)](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html) for this and other parameter extensions.

Comment: Very thorough answer! I will check the options and post feedback.

Comment: Feedback #1: I do not know why you set 3 levels of "worthiness" for your solutions (perhaps you could comment on the reasons). At any rate, for the intended use, as posted in the OP, I found the first one is useful, since it allows for extracting the app name without .exe, for later use. The following two alternatives only detect if .exe is present, but they do not isolate the app name.

Comment: @DavidPostill - Your comment is worth an answer.

Comment: I have added a summarizing answer below, showing the appropriate line of code, http://superuser.com/a/947474/245595

Answer (score 1):

#### How to do I use the parameter with .exe removed (for the directory part)?

You can use `%~n1`.

This expands `%1` to a file name without the file extension.

---

#### Parameter Extensions

> When an argument is used to supply a filename then the following
>   extended syntax can be applied:
>
> We are using the variable %1 (but this works for any parameter)
>
> - `%~f1` - Expand %1 to a Fully qualified path name - C:\utils\MyFile.txt
> - `%~d1` - Expand %1 to a Drive letter only - C:
> - `%~p1` - Expand %1 to a Path only e.g. \utils\ this includes a trailing \ which will be interpreted as an escape character by some
>     commands.
> - `%~n1` - Expand %1 to a file Name without file extension C:\utils\MyFile or if only a path is present (with no trailing
>     backslash) - the last folder in that path.
> - `%~x1` - Expand %1 to a file eXtension only - .txt
> - `%~s1` - Change the meaning of f, n, s and x to reference the Short 8.3 name (if it exists.)
> - `%~1` -  Expand %1 removing any surrounding quotes (")
> - `%~a1` - Display the file attributes of %1
> - `%~t1` - Display the date/time of %1
> - `%~z1` - Display the file size of %1
> - `%~$PATH:1` - Search the PATH environment variable and expand %1 to the fully qualified name of the first match found.
>
> The modifiers above can be combined:
>
> - `%~dp1` - Expand %1 to a drive letter and path only
> - `%~sp1` - Expand %1 to a path shortened to 8.3 characters
> - `%~nx2` - Expand %2 to a file name and extension only

Source [parameters](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html)

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [parameters](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html) - A command line argument (or parameter) is any value passed into a batch script.

Answer (score 0):

I will answer the specific question posted:
*What should the line in the `.bat` file be?*,
which was split into 3 necessary steps.

JosefZ [answered](https://superuser.com/a/932431/245595) separately the 3 points leading to the answer.
DavidPostill [gave another option](https://superuser.com/a/947464/245595) for point 2.

The resulting code would be

```
set "app1=%~1"
if "%app1%"=="" (
  echo No parameter supplied. This should be run as
  echo   regadd.bat myapp.exe
  echo or
  echo   regadd.bat myapp
  goto :eof
) else (
  REM set "app=%app1:.exe=%"
  set "app=%~n1"
)
if "%app%"=="%app1%" (
  REM echo .exe not present
) else (
  REM echo .exe present
)
echo App is %app%
reg add "HKCR\Applications\%app%.exe\shell\open\command" /ve /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /d "\"%%MYAPPSDIR%%\%app%\%app%.exe\" \"%%1\"" /f
```